# PyInstaller Missing Module Errors Even After Including Specifically

Tags: python, macos, compilation, pyinstaller

Pyinstaller compiles my app into an .exe on Windows fine, but I'm not able to build a working .app on Mac. I've tried --onefile and --onedir, but no dice, the app just opens and then closes immediately reporting a crash. It looks like a module import issue, but I've tried importing all the modules I know how through the .spec file in pathex and datas. I've reinstalled pyinstaller to both release and dev versions. Any ideas what else I can try? Thanks!

**SYSTEM:**
PyInstaller: 3.3.1
Python: 3.6.3
Platform: Darwin-16.7.0-x86_64-i386-64bit

**COMMAND:**
pyinstaller --onedir --name=StaticBot --windowed StaticBot.spec

**SPEC FILE:**

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['../main.py'],
             pathex=[
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5',
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil', 
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/grid_objs',
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/offline',
                 '/Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot'
             ],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[ ('../res_rc.py', '.'), 
                ('../ui.py', '.'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/plotly/', './plotly/plotly/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/grid_objs/', './plotly/grid_objs/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/offline/', './plotly/offline/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/default-schema.json', './plotly/package_data/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/graphWidget.js', './plotly/package_data/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/plotly.min.js', './plotly/package_data/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil', './psutil')
                ],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='Staticbot',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          icon='/Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/_output_mac/Staticbot.icns',
          console=False )
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='Staticbot.app',
             icon='/Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/_output_mac/Staticbot.icns',
             bundle_identifier=None)
```

**WARNING LIST:**

```
missing module named pyimod03_importers - imported by /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_pkgres.py
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements, pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.markers
missing module named netbios - imported by uuid
missing module named win32wnet - imported by uuid
missing module named __builtin__ - imported by numpy.core.numerictypes, numpy.core.numeric, numpy.distutils.misc_util, numpy.lib.function_base, numpy.lib._iotools, numpy.ma.core, numpy, pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing
missing module named ordereddict - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.pyparsing
missing module named 'com.sun' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
missing module named com - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
missing module named win32api - imported by distutils.msvccompiler, pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
missing module named 'win32com.shell' - imported by pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
missing module named StringIO - imported by six, urllib3.packages.six, requests.compat, numpy.lib.utils, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils, numpy.lib.format, pkg_resources._vendor.six
missing module named __main__ - imported by pkg_resources
missing module named multiprocessing.SimpleQueue - imported by multiprocessing, concurrent.futures.process
missing module named multiprocessing.set_start_method - imported by multiprocessing, multiprocessing.spawn
missing module named multiprocessing.get_start_method - imported by multiprocessing, multiprocessing.spawn
missing module named multiprocessing.TimeoutError - imported by multiprocessing, multiprocessing.pool
missing module named multiprocessing.get_context - imported by multiprocessing, multiprocessing.pool, multiprocessing.managers, multiprocessing.sharedctypes
missing module named multiprocessing.BufferTooShort - imported by multiprocessing, multiprocessing.connection
missing module named multiprocessing.AuthenticationError - imported by multiprocessing, multiprocessing.connection
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.packaging - imported by pkg_resources.extern, pkg_resources, setuptools.dist, setuptools.command.egg_info
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.appdirs - imported by pkg_resources.extern, pkg_resources
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.six.moves' - imported by pkg_resources, pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.requirements
missing module named pkg_resources.extern.six - imported by pkg_resources.extern, pkg_resources
missing module named 'multiprocessing.forking' - imported by /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/loader/rthooks/pyi_rth_multiprocessing.py
excluded module named _frozen_importlib - imported by importlib, importlib.abc, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named _frozen_importlib_external - imported by importlib._bootstrap, importlib, importlib.abc, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named _winreg - imported by platform, requests.utils, numpy.distutils.cpuinfo, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py, pkg_resources._vendor.appdirs
missing module named java - imported by platform, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named 'java.lang' - imported by platform, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py, xml.sax._exceptions
missing module named vms_lib - imported by platform, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named msvcrt - imported by subprocess, getpass, multiprocessing.spawn, multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32, numpy.distutils.mingw32ccompiler, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named _winapi - imported by subprocess, multiprocessing.reduction, multiprocessing.connection, multiprocessing.heap, multiprocessing.popen_spawn_win32, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named winreg - imported by platform, mimetypes, urllib.request, requests.utils, distutils.msvccompiler, distutils.msvc9compiler, distutils._msvccompiler, numpy.distutils.cpuinfo, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named urllib.splittag - imported by urllib, setuptools.py26compat
missing module named urllib.getproxies_environment - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass_environment - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.proxy_bypass - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.getproxies - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.urlencode - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.unquote_plus - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.quote_plus - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.unquote - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named urllib.quote - imported by urllib, requests.compat
missing module named _dummy_threading - imported by dummy_threading, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named nt - imported by os, ntpath, shutil, pathlib, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named 'org.python' - imported by copy, setuptools.sandbox, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py, xml.sax
missing module named org - imported by pickle, /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named Queue - imported by urllib3.connectionpool
missing module named "'urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib'.parse" - imported by urllib3.request, urllib3.poolmanager
runtime module named urllib3.packages.six.moves - imported by http.client, urllib3.connectionpool, urllib3.util.response, 'urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib', urllib3.response
missing module named backports - imported by urllib3.packages.ssl_match_hostname
missing module named socks - imported by urllib3.contrib.socks
missing module named 'OpenSSL.crypto' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
missing module named 'cryptography.x509' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
missing module named 'cryptography.hazmat' - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
missing module named cryptography - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
missing module named OpenSSL - imported by urllib3.contrib.pyopenssl
missing module named _abcoll - imported by urllib3.packages.ordered_dict
missing module named dummy_thread - imported by urllib3.packages.ordered_dict, numpy.core.arrayprint
missing module named thread - imported by urllib3.packages.ordered_dict, numpy.core.arrayprint
missing module named Cookie - imported by requests.compat
missing module named cookielib - imported by requests.compat
missing module named urllib2 - imported by requests.compat, setuptools.package_index, numpy.lib._datasource
missing module named urlparse - imported by requests.compat, numpy.lib._datasource
missing module named simplejson - imported by requests.compat
missing module named IPython - imported by plotly.plotly.plotly
runtime module named six.moves - imported by plotly.plotly.plotly, plotly.plotly.chunked_requests.chunked_request, 'six.moves.urllib'
missing module named "'six.moves.urllib'.parse" - imported by plotly.plotly.chunked_requests.chunked_request
missing module named pandas - imported by plotly.graph_objs.graph_objs, plotly.figure_factory._county_choropleth
missing module named numpy.lib.i0 - imported by numpy.lib, numpy.dual
missing module named numpy.linalg.inv - imported by numpy.linalg, numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix, numpy.lib.polynomial
missing module named cPickle - imported by numpy.core.numeric, numpy.lib.format, numpy.lib.npyio, numpy.ma.core
missing module named cStringIO - imported by cPickle
missing module named copy_reg - imported by cPickle, cStringIO, numpy.core
missing module named ConfigParser - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info, numpy.distutils.npy_pkg_config
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose
missing module named 'numpy_distutils.command' - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose
missing module named numpy_distutils - imported by numpy.f2py.diagnose
missing module named numpy.testing.memusage - imported by numpy.testing, numpy.f2py.f2py_testing
missing module named numpy.testing.jiffies - imported by numpy.testing, numpy.f2py.f2py_testing
missing module named setuptools_svn - imported by setuptools.command.egg_info
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.six' - imported by setuptools, setuptools.extension
missing module named wincertstore - imported by setuptools.ssl_support
missing module named 'backports.ssl_match_hostname' - imported by setuptools.ssl_support
missing module named win32com - imported by setuptools.sandbox
missing module named 'pkg_resources.extern.packaging.version' - imported by setuptools.msvc
missing module named 'setuptools.extern.six.moves' - imported by setuptools.dist, setuptools.command.easy_install, setuptools.sandbox, setuptools.command.setopt, setuptools.package_index, setuptools.ssl_support, setuptools.command.egg_info, setuptools.command.py36compat, setuptools.msvc
missing module named setuptools.extern.six - imported by setuptools.extern, setuptools.monkey, setuptools.dist, setuptools.depends, setuptools.command.easy_install, setuptools.sandbox, setuptools.package_index, setuptools.command.bdist_egg, setuptools.command.egg_info, setuptools.command.sdist, setuptools.unicode_utils, setuptools.glob, setuptools.command.develop
missing module named _findvs - imported by distutils._msvccompiler
missing module named __svn_version__ - imported by numpy.f2py.__version__
missing module named numarray - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info
missing module named Numeric - imported by numpy.distutils.system_info
missing module named commands - imported by numpy.distutils.cpuinfo
missing module named 'nose.plugins' - imported by numpy.testing.nose_tools.noseclasses, numpy.testing.nose_tools.nosetester
missing module named scipy - imported by numpy.testing.nose_tools.nosetester
missing module named 'nose.util' - imported by numpy.testing.nose_tools.noseclasses
missing module named nose - imported by numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils, numpy.testing.nose_tools.decorators, numpy.testing.nose_tools.noseclasses
missing module named numpy.core.number - imported by numpy.core, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named numpy.lib.imag - imported by numpy.lib, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named numpy.lib.real - imported by numpy.lib, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named numpy.lib.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy.lib, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named numpy.core.signbit - imported by numpy.core, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named win32pdh - imported by numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named numpy.core.float64 - imported by numpy.core, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named numpy.core.float32 - imported by numpy.core, numpy.testing.nose_tools.utils
missing module named win32con - imported by distutils.msvccompiler
missing module named numpy.core.integer - imported by numpy.core, numpy.fft.helper
missing module named numpy.core.sqrt - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg, numpy.fft.fftpack
missing module named numpy.core.conjugate - imported by numpy.core, numpy.fft.fftpack
missing module named numpy.lib.triu - imported by numpy.lib, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.divide - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.object_ - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.intp - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.longdouble - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.geterrobj - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.maximum - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.add - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.complexfloating - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.inexact - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.cdouble - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.csingle - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.double - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named numpy.core.single - imported by numpy.core, numpy.linalg.linalg
missing module named future_builtins - imported by numpy.lib.npyio
missing module named numpy.recarray - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.mrecords
missing module named numpy.dtype - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.mrecords, numpy.ctypeslib
missing module named numpy.expand_dims - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core
missing module named numpy.array - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core, numpy.ma.extras, numpy.ma.mrecords, numpy.ctypeslib
missing module named numpy.bool_ - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core, numpy.ma.mrecords
missing module named numpy.iscomplexobj - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core
missing module named numpy.amin - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core
missing module named numpy.amax - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core
missing module named numpy.ndarray - imported by numpy, numpy.ma.core, numpy.ma.extras, numpy.ma.mrecords, numpy.ctypeslib
missing module named numpy.histogramdd - imported by numpy, numpy.lib.twodim_base
missing module named numpy.eye - imported by numpy, numpy.core.numeric
missing module named sets - imported by pytz.tzinfo
missing module named UserDict - imported by pytz.lazy
missing module named psutil._psutil_aix - imported by psutil, psutil._psaix
missing module named psutil._psutil_sunos - imported by psutil, psutil._pssunos
missing module named psutil._psutil_bsd - imported by psutil, psutil._psbsd
missing module named psutil._psutil_windows - imported by psutil, psutil._pswindows
missing module named _psutil_linux - imported by psutil
missing module named win32process - imported by /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
missing module named win32gui - imported by /Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot/main.py
```

Comment: This is the solution of all of these that worked for me, but I wish it generalized better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. Looks like the solution was a combination of using --onedir instead of --onefile and switching back to the latest release of PyInstaller instead of the dev pyqt5-fix version, and setting org.qt-project.Qt.QtWebEngineCore as the bundle_identifier. Also make sure you have Qt5 installed in addition to PyQt5.

**Command**

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name=Staticbot --windowed Staticbot.spec
```

**Requirements**

System

- Python 3.6.5
- qt 5.10.1

Python

- PyQt5 5.10.1
- PyInstaller 3.3.1
- Spec File

**Spec File**

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['../main.py'],
            pathex=[
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6',
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil', 
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/grid_objs',
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/offline',
                 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5',
                 '/Users/justint/Documents/Justin/Dev/Staticbot'
             ],
              binaries=[],
              datas=[('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/plotly/', './plotly/plotly/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/grid_objs/', './plotly/grid_objs/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/offline/', './plotly/offline/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/default-schema.json', './plotly/package_data/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/graphWidget.js', './plotly/package_data/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/plotly/package_data/plotly.min.js', './plotly/package_data/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebEngine.so', './PyQt5/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebEngineCore.so', './PyQt5/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/QtWebEngineWidgets.so', './PyQt5/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/QtWebEngineProcess.app', './PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtWebEngineCore.framework/Helpers/'),
                ('/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/psutil', './psutil')
                ],
              hiddenimports=[],
              hookspath=[],
              runtime_hooks=[],
              excludes=[],
              win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
              win_private_assemblies=False,
              cipher=block_cipher)

pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)


exe = EXE(pyz,
            a.scripts,
            exclude_binaries=True,
            name='Staticbot',
            debug=False,
            strip=False,
            upx=False,
            console=False )


coll = COLLECT( exe,
                a.binaries,
                a.scripts,
                a.zipfiles,
                a.datas,
                strip=False,
                upx=False,
                name='Staticbot')

app = BUNDLE(coll,
             name='Staticbot.app',
             bundle_identifier='org.qt-project.Qt.QtWebEngineCore')
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to run the correct pyinstaller when you're using a virtual env. You need to use the one that is installed in that specific venv.

Comment: This was it for me, using the globally installed one, even though it was the same version number did not work. You have to use the one from the venv you are using for the file

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to determine why the .app is not running, but it may be due to a missing module, as you suggest. You can more easily see the error message associated with the premature closing of the application by running the .app from the terminal (rather than double-clicking the executable file):

```
/path/to/app/dist/MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/MyApp
```

If this reports an error that you can not debug, add it to your question as an edit.

If the program fails because it has failed to import a module, you can add the module to the hiddenimports list in the .spec file and run PyInstaller again (`pyinstaller myfile.spec`). Or you could add the following option to your PyInstaller command:

```
pyinstaller [options] --hiddenimport=missing_module myfile.py
```

I do not think that importing the modules through the pathex or datas lists is the recommended way to explicitly add them.

Comment: Thanks, I'm getting closer, now running it in terminal is giving me this error: **Could not find QtWebEngineProcess**. Tried including QtWebEngineWidgets.so, QtWebEngineCore.so, QtWebEngine.so, but no luck yet. Gonna keep trying things...

Comment: In case you haven't seen it yet, this thread may be useful: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/3308

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem for a lot of people, for some reason I'm still getting `Could not find QtWebEngineProcess Abort trap: 6` even when running that pyinstaller-pyqt5_fix version of pyinstaller. Tried adding it to missing_modules, pathex, and datas but nothing is working so far.