# Pyinstaller: "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyutil'" when running .exe file

Tags: python, pyinstaller, modulenotfounderror

If I use `pyinstaller` to package my Python script into a `.exe` file, when I run the `.exe` file, it throws an error as shown below:

1. Packaging the script into a `.exe` file, there is no error:

   ```
   (venv) E:\workspace\PycharmProjects\google-authenticator>pyinstaller -F --hidden-import=pyutil google-authenticator.py
   126 INFO: PyInstaller: 4.2
   126 INFO: Python: 3.8.6
   128 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
   129 INFO: wrote E:\workspace\PycharmProjects\google-authenticator\google-authenticator.spec
   141 INFO: UPX is not available.
   142 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
   ['E:\\workspace\\PycharmProjects\\google-authenticator',
    'E:\\workspace\\PycharmProjects\\google-authenticator']
   179 INFO: checking Analysis
   264 INFO: checking PYZ
   315 INFO: checking PKG
   330 INFO: Building because E:\workspace\PycharmProjects\google-authenticator\build\google-authenticator\google-authenticator.exe.manifest changed
   330 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
   3027 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
   3031 INFO: Bootloader c:\python38\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-64bit\run.exe
   3031 INFO: checking EXE
   3033 INFO: Rebuilding EXE-00.toc because google-authenticator.exe missing
   3033 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
   3036 INFO: Copying icons from ['c:\\python38\\lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\bootloader\\images\\icon-console.ico']
   3037 INFO: Writing RT_GROUP_ICON 0 resource with 104 bytes
   3038 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 1 resource with 3752 bytes
   3038 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 2 resource with 2216 bytes
   3038 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 3 resource with 1384 bytes
   3038 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 4 resource with 37019 bytes
   3039 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 5 resource with 9640 bytes
   3039 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 6 resource with 4264 bytes
   3039 INFO: Writing RT_ICON 7 resource with 1128 bytes
   3053 INFO: Updating manifest in E:\workspace\PycharmProjects\google-authenticator\build\google-authenticator\run.exe.ed6jwwbz
   3054 INFO: Updating resource type 24 name 1 language 0
   3058 INFO: Appending archive to EXE E:\workspace\PycharmProjects\google-authenticator\dist\google-authenticator.exe
   3070 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
   ```
2. when I run the `.exe` file, it meets the following error:

   ```
   E:\workspace\PycharmProjects\google-authenticator\dist>google-authenticator.exe
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "google-authenticator.py", line 6, in <module>
   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyutil'
   [37916] Failed to execute script google-authenticator
   ```

Comment: Try using spec file, and mention all used libraries.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50400037/12865727